# Ruby encapsulate/package existing code into a namespace

Tags: ruby, module, nested, namespaces

I've been looking all around and didn't found any kind of answer to the problem i'm facing in Ruby. I'm writing an app that use core modules sets that are available in different versions. If I'm sourcing a core set version after an another one both code version will be sourced at the same and will clash with each other. That is quite normal and I'm ok with this.

One approach could be to unload the previous version to load the new one but I'd like to keep all the ones loaded into specific namespaces (to avoid time consuming to unload/reload code all the time). 2 possible solutions to me (or maybe other)

1. Either source the code then move it into a version namespace (some clues to do it see below but doesn't work yet)
2. Or source the code directly into a version namespace (don't know how to do it exactly, maybe with module_eval but need to recode the require process with dependencies). Does any solution seems possible ?

Here is a very simple poc of what I'm trying to achieve

**file : coreset_1.0.0.rb**

```
module CoreA
  def self.who_am_i?; self.to_s; end
  def self.get_coreb; CoreB end
end

module CoreB
  def self.who_am_i?; self.to_s; end
end
```

**file : coreset_2.0.0.rb** (got some changes)

```
module CoreA
  def self.my_name; self.to_s; end
  def self.get_coreb; CoreB end
end

module CoreB
  def self.my_name; self.to_s; end
end
```

**file : coreManager.rb**

```
module CoreManager
  def self.load_version(arg_version)
     #Create a module set for the selected version
     core_set_name = CoreSet + '_' + arg_version.gsub('.', '_')
     core_set = eval("Module #{core_set_name}; end; #{core_set_name}"

     #Load the requested code
     require "coreset_#{arg_version}.rb"

     #Move loaded code into it core set module
     core_set.const_set(:CoreA, Object.send(:remove_const, :CoreA))
     core_set.const_set(:CoreB, Object.send(:remove_const,:CoreB))

     #Return the created core set
     core_set
  end
end
```

**If running the code :**

```
require 'coreManager.rb'
core_set = CoreManager.load_version("1.0.0")
puts core_set::CoreA.who_am_i?
puts core_set::CoreA.get_coreB
```

it returns :

```
CoreA #not CoreSet_1_0_0::CoreA
uninitialized constant CoreA::CoreB (NameError)
```

**If running something statically defined, it works**

```
module CoreSet
  module CoreA
    def self.who_am_i?; self.to_s; end
    def self.get_coreb; CoreB end
  end

  module CoreB
    def self.who_am_i?; self.to_s; end
  end
end

CoreSet::CoreA.get_coreb
```

It returns as expected :

```
CoreSet::CoreB
```

Depite of what is usually said :"a module is a constant", it seems to be more than that. What are the differencies and how to make the dynamic version working ?

Any other ideas ?

Thanks for your help folks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things broken in your code (which is ok for POC, I guess), but the main one is that `require` loads constants and globals into the global namespace.

So, your `Core<X>` modules are not namespaced this way, as you might expect. There is `Kernel#load` method that allows "wrapped" execution of the loaded file, but it's wrapped into an anonymous module, so you can prevent the global namespace from being polluted, but you cannot "target" the constants to be defined into a particular namespace this way.

What you could try is to load the code as text and then eval it within the dynamically created module, matching your version. For example, look at this quick and very dirty sketch (`coreset_...rb` files are expected to sit into `coresets` directory):

```rb
module CoreSet; end

class CoreManager
  class << self
    def load_version(ver)
      raise "Vesion #{ver} unknown" unless exists?(ver)

      file = filename(ver)
      code = File.read(file)

      versioned_wrapper = Module.new do
        class_eval code
      end

      CoreSet.const_set("V_#{ver.gsub('.', '_')}", versioned_wrapper)
    end

    private

    def exists?(ver)
      File.exists? filename(ver)
    end

    def filename(ver)
      "coresets/coreset_#{ver.gsub('.', '_')}.rb"
    end
  end
end

CoreManager.load_version("1.0.0")
CoreManager.load_version("2.0.0")

p CoreSet::V_1_0_0::CoreA.who_am_i? # => "CoreSet::V_1_0_0::CoreA"
p CoreSet::V_1_0_0::CoreA.get_coreb # => CoreSet::V_1_0_0::CoreB
p CoreSet::V_2_0_0::CoreA.my_name # => "CoreSet::V_2_0_0::CoreA"
p CoreSet::V_2_0_0::CoreA.get_coreb # => CoreSet::V_2_0_0::CoreB
```

But, DON'T do this at home, please :) At least, I would think twice.

If all you need is to have all the versions loaded at once (you need namespaces exactly for this, right?) what stops you from defining them statically, like `CoreSet::V1::Core<X>` etc and use the idiomatic and safe ways to (auto)load them? :) Playing with dynamic nested constants definition  (and, especially, their removing) is one of the easiest ways to shoot your own foot...

Comment: Thanks Konstantin for your answer. You got it right this POC is really minimalist regarding the real code. I've been thinking of converting source files to string eval but the problem is that each core module as dozen of class files which have dependencies with each other due to class inheritance. So sourcing them manually by evaluating source code is not an option either it would leads me to code a sourcing with depencies which is exctly what the require command does... Moreover when testing this solution I got some eval errors too, I definitly agree with you if there is no other options

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally came to a solution that may help others or that can be discussed.

Getting the error ***uninitialized constant CoreA::CoreB (NameError)*** leads me to take the problem under a new angle. If I'm not able to access to CoreB module from CoreA (because the module nesting has been broken when redefining module constants into the CoreSet module) then why not referencing in each core module the other ones in the set ? And finaly it works without any dirty hack, I'm just creating pointers and the Ruby Core find it natively ;)

```
module CoreManager
  def self.load_version(arg_version)
     #Create a module set for the selected version
     core_set_name = CoreSet + '_' + arg_version.gsub('.', '_')
     core_set = eval("Module #{core_set_name}; end; #{core_set_name}"

     #Load the requested code
     toplevel_consts = Object.constants
     require "coreset_#{arg_version}.rb"
     core_modules = Object.constants - toplevel_consts

     #Move the core modules to the set namespace
     core_modules.collect! do |core_module|
       core_module_sym = core_module.to_s.to_sym
       core_set.const_set(core_module_sym, Object.send(:remove_const, core_module_sym))
       eval("#{core_set}::#{core_module}")
     end

     #Create connexion between set cores to skirt broken module nesting
     core_modules.each do |current_core|
       core_modules.each do |other_core|
         current_core.const_set(other_core.to_s.to_sym, other_core) unless current_core == other_core
       end
     end

     #Return the created core set
     core_set
  end
end
```